# Blender 3.4 won't run citing unsupported graphics card but 3.3 works

Tags: error, opengl

I have 3 computers I primarily run Blender on, 2 of which are giving me this error:

```
**Error! Unsupported graphics card or driver.
A graphics card and driver with support for OpenGL 3.3 or higher is required.
The program will now close.**
```

but if I run Blender 3.3 on those machines, it works perfectly.

Computer 1 is Ubuntu 20.04 with an AMD GPU, it runs 3.4
Computer 2 is Ubuntu 20.04 with intel graphics only, it shows the symptoms above
Computer 3 is old hardware running Mint 20 with NVidia graphics, it shows the above.

3.3 works fine on all three computers.

an example of `glxinfo | grep -i opengl`
(from computer 2)

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel

OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)

OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 21.2.2

OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60

OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)

OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile

OpenGL core profile extensions:

OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 21.2.2

OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60

OpenGL context flags: (none)

OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile

OpenGL extensions:

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 21.2.2

OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20

OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I think this means its running OpenGL 4.6?
From my research though, the minimum requirement for OpenGL 3.3 is not new to Blender 3.4, this actually became a requirement a long time ago. but I am suddenly seeing this problem.